# Sumatoria de elementos de un JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy consumiendo un JSON para formar un reporte, el JSON es como este:

```
[
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 84,
        "tipo": 2,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:27:37.513",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Corte y persing ",
        "correccion": " ",
        "elemento": "2022083001071M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 85,
        "tipo": 2,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:28:18.597",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Corte y persing ",
        "correccion": " ",
        "elemento": "2022083000891M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    }
]
```

Dentro del reporte debo entregar una tabla donde una de sus columnas es el `numeroparte` y otra columna es el total, es decir, si `numeroparte` se repite `n` cantidad de veces, debo sumar su valor de `cantidad`, debo esperar algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una función donde el JSON lo trato como una matriz, obtengo el primer elemento en su propiedad `numeroparte` y lo comparo contra el resto, hasta ahí obtengo la sumatoria del primer elemento,  el siguiente paso que veo seria, comprobar si ya hice el conteo de ese elemento, para eso uso el arreglo `part_market`, donde ingreso los elementos dentro del ciclo, mas adelante me sirve para comprobar si debo o no agregar `data_report` a la sumatoria que hice, pero no agrega ningún dato.

```
function build_totals(array)//Construye totales para cada parte encontrada en el reportel
{
    var part_market = [];//Para almacenar los elementos que he validado
    for (var d = 0; d < array.length; d++)
    {
        var count = 0;
        part_market.push(array[d].numeroparte);

        for (var e = 0; e < array.length; e++)
        {
            if (array[e].numeroparte == array[d].numeroparte)
            {
                count = count + array[e].cantidad;
            }
        }
        if (!part_market.includes(array[d].numeroparte))//Si el elemento no se encuentra agregarlo al array
        { data_report.push({ NumParte: array[d].numeroparte, Cantidad: count }); }
    }
    console.log(data_report);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te muestro una solución en la que creo un objeto en el que le voy agregando propiedades "numeroparte" y como valor le asigno la cantidad y en caso de ya existir la llave le sumo la cantidad.

Creo que es lo que buscas y si no pues te servirá de ayuda

```js
const dataArray = [
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 84,
        "tipo": 2,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:27:37.513",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Corte y persing ",
        "correccion": " ",
        "elemento": "2022083001071M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 85,
        "tipo": 2,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:28:18.597",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Corte y persing ",
        "correccion": " ",
        "elemento": "2022083000891M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    }
];

function arrayToSpecialTable(arr) {
  
  const parsedObj = {};
  
  arr.forEach(item =>{
    if (parsedObj.hasOwnProperty(item.numeroparte)) {
      parsedObj[item.numeroparte] += item.cantidad;
    } else {
      parsedObj[item.numeroparte] = item.cantidad;
    }
  });
  
  console.log(parsedObj)
  console.table(parsedObj)
}

arrayToSpecialTable(dataArray)
```

Comment: Efectivamente, es exactamente lo que necesitaba hacer, ahora debo de entenderlo.

Answer (score 1):

Si tuvieras que hacer muchas de estas tablas, tal vez te conviene revisar esta libreráa [alasql](https://github.com/AlaSQL/alasql). Con la cual puedes hacer una consulta SQL a un arreglo javascript

```js
const DATOS =[
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 80,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:04.353",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001031M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 81,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:24:32.963",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001001M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 82,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:21.173",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001041M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "TUBE COMP, FUEL VENT (ORVR)",
        "numeroparte": "17725-17B-L710-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "CLIP, ABSORBER",
        "numeroparte": "91591-17B-3000",
        "cantidad": 3,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 83,
        "tipo": 1,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:25:48.97",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Welding 5",
        "correccion": "Breather desfasado",
        "elemento": "2022083001021M8003",
        "nombre": "PIPE COMP, FUEL FILLER",
        "numeroparte": "17660-3W0-A040-Y1",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 84,
        "tipo": 2,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:27:37.513",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Corte y persing ",
        "correccion": " ",
        "elemento": "2022083001071M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "idscrap": 85,
        "tipo": 2,
        "fecha": "2022-09-01T15:28:18.597",
        "modelo": "3W0-A0",
        "estacion": "Corte y persing ",
        "correccion": " ",
        "elemento": "2022083000891M8003",
        "nombre": "BODY, FUEL TANK",
        "numeroparte": "17500-3W0-A020-20",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "comment": ""
    }
];

var res = alasql('SELECT numeroparte, SUM(cantidad) AS Cantidad FROM ? GROUP BY numeroparte', [DATOS] );

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alasql@2"></script>
```

Comment: Buena esa, me hubiera ahorrado un par de horas